# How much customization can be applied to a Java Swing object?

Tags: java, html, swing, user-interface

Coming over to Java from C#, new to Swing desktop GUI. Is it possible to style a desktop application window, such as corner radius (none), background color, etc.? Or are these dictated by the platform?

I've been looking into Swing can't seem to find methods to style the window extremities like the UI shell itself. Looking for a non-native look similar to CEF3 applications like Brackets, Steam which use chromium's HTML5 UI framework and a client / server application model.

To be clear, I'm talking about the window border with:

`setUndecorated(false)`

Comment: Quite a bit, but you'll have to modify the [L&F](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/) yourself.

Comment: Maybe you'll be more interested in `JavaFX` as it's a `Swing` successor. You'll have there observables, CSS styling rules & quite a lot of features of modern desktop apps.

Comment: @Xeon this looks more promising. And for web deployment I'm guessing there's room for portability?

Comment: JavaFX is now part of the JRE/JDK for Java 8 so if the user has Java 8 installation it should run without any errors. For packaging maybe [this article about deployment](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm) will help or maybe [IzPack](http://izpack.org/)?